# Number is saved in database as Number - 1

Tags: php, yii2

I have a function that receives a value `amount`, that is a float number. This number is multiplied by 100 to be converted to a whole number, before it is saved into the database. Dumping the variable after the multiplication shows that its value is 6699. When saving the number to the db (in an int column) it is saved as 6688 though! What can be wrong

Comment: show the code to make it more clear

Comment: try to round the amount `round($amount)`

Comment: 'amount' => '66,99' , this value is not integer

Comment: Yes I mutlitply by 100 before saving. I dumped the value just before $model->save() and the value just before $model->save() is 6699

Comment: @madalinivascu what do you mean? :)

Comment: php saves in memory 6699  as 6698.99999999999 so when you send it to the db its truncated to 6698

Comment: Actually I think this is the issue. I dumped the variable and it turns out that its float. Ill try changing it to int

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken for more info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157467/discussion-between-mrateb-and-madalinivascu).